# Toggling caret-up/don button not happening in javascript because of specificity i think

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome

I have a scenario where by default "fa-caret-up" is set but on clicking it, it should change to
fa-caret-down. I am toggling it and i am using font-awesome.

**HTML code:**

```
 <span id="caret" class="caret-box"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></span>
```

**javascript:**

```
let caretEl = document.getElementById("caret");
caretEl.addEventListener("click", function(){
        caretEl.childNodes[0].classList.toggle("fa-caret-up");     
});
```

I want to know how to toggle this. In normal scenario it works but in this particular scenario its not working may be because of high specificity of "fa-caret-down".

Comment: What you mean by "its not working" ??? how you expect it to work? ... i think you want to toggle between 'fa-caret-down' and 'fa-caret-up' so pass both classes to the toggle method: ```caretEl.childNodes[0].classList.toggle("fa-caret-up fa-caret-down");```

Answer (score 0):

```
let caretEl = document.getElementById("caret");
caretEl.addEventListener("click", function(){

     // this is in HTML so this will get removed/added
      caretEl.childNodes[0].classList.toggle("fa-caret-down");

      caretEl.childNodes[0].classList.toggle("fa-caret-up");     
});
```